# Selection sort Big-Oh notation analysis

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, big-o, selection-sort

What steps are required in determining the Big-Oh notation for the algorithm when sorting an array of integers 5 7 4 9 8 5 6 3 and showing the contents each time a selection sort changes it while sorting the array into ascending order and descending order? I need to do an evaluation of the Big-Oh notation before I come up with a Java program to sort the elements in ascending and descending order

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation/487278#487278

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Answer (score 0):

When finding the Big Oh for any algorithm, you must count the number of instructions that are performed in the algorithm, usually by finding a pattern for when they are performed. You must also consider the instructions that occur in the worst case (i.e. when searching a list, worst case is that visit every element). For selection sort, a simplified break down of the algorithm it that for a list of n elements, each element is compared the other elements in the list. The switching of elements and the printing of the n elements also occurs essentially for every element. Roughly this would look like this in code:

- ### For every n element

  -Go through list and compare with every other element to the right of element

  -If the minimum element to right sub-array is less than the current element, switch

  -Print n elements in array.

So this will look like n*(n+1+n) which essentially is O(n^2)
If your algorithm wants to do both ascending and descending, it doubles the n^2 which is still O(n^2)